# Create a XML document using the DOM object with white characters

Tags: php, xml, dom

I have a question: I am trying to create a XML file using DomDocument and I would like to have this output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<winstrom version="1.0">
<main_tag>
<child_tag>example</child_tag>
</main_tag>
<winstrom>
```

The problem is with the second row - if I write it as below then the output is "Invalid Character Error". I guess it is not allowed to have space characters there... However I need it like this, so what are the options?

```
$dom = new DomDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');

$root = $dom->createElement('winstrom version=1.0');
$dom->appendChild($root);

$item = $dom->createElement('hlavni_tag');
$root2->appendChild($item);

$text = $dom->createTextNode('example');
$item->appendChild($text);

$dom->formatOutput = true;
echo $dom->saveXML();
```

Comment: could you sub it for an undescore, if not what about a HTML entity &nbsp;

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a misunderstanding of what an XML element is and how it differs from attributes.

Try this code:

```
<?php 
$dom = new DomDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');

$root = $dom->createElement('winstrom');
$root->setAttribute("version","1.0");
$dom->appendChild($root);

$root2 = $dom->createElement("main_tag"); //You forgot this part
$root->appendChild($root2);

$item = $dom->createElement('hlavni_tag'); //Should it be "child_tag"?
$root2->appendChild($item);

$text = $dom->createTextNode('example');
$item->appendChild($text);

$dom->formatOutput = true;
echo $dom->saveXML();
```

Comment: You, sir, deserve a medail... Thank you very much... When I see it now it becomes quite obvious... Need to study... moreee!

Comment: Welcome to SO, lada Prchal, it is good practise to "accept" an helpful answer by klicking on the check mark.